# Find the count of elements in a group Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample data set like this,

```
toy_df = pd.DataFrame()

toy_df['A'] = ['ABC', 'ABC', 'XYZ', 'ABC', 'XYZ']
toy_df['B'] = ['AX', 'BX', 'AX', 'AX', 'AX']
```

I want to group this dataset by columns 'A' and then find the number of occurrences of each value in 'B' as a `dict`.

While grouping and finding unique elements I get like this,

```
toy_df.groupby(by=['A'])['B'].unique()

A
ABC    [AX, BX]
XYZ        [AX]
Name: B, dtype: object
```

I want to get something like shown below,

```
A
ABC    {'AX' : 2, 'BX' : 1}
XYZ    {'AX' : 2}
Name: B, dtype: object
```

How can I do this in pandas.?

Comment: possibly i am misunderstanding the question but can't you just use `sum()` instead of `unique()`?

Comment: @Nullman `sum` will give a concatenated string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `dict.fromkeys`:

```
a  = toy_df.groupby(by=['A'])['B'].unique().apply(lambda x: dict.fromkeys(x, 1))
print (a)
A
ABC    {'AX': 1, 'BX': 1}
XYZ             {'AX': 1}
Name: B, dtype: object
```

EDIT: For count values to dictionary use `Counter` in dictionary comprehension:

```
from collections import Counter

a  = pd.Series({i: Counter(g) for i, g in toy_df.groupby(by=['A'])['B']})
print (a)
ABC    {'AX': 2, 'BX': 1}
XYZ             {'AX': 2}
dtype: object
```

Comment: there was an error in the required result I posted, I haved edited now. Please take a look now

Comment: Cool, this is what I am looking for. Thanks jezrael